# Commas in my sentence

Tags: word-choice

Should I use commas in the way I did and isn't it unnecessary to say that it's a day off because a public holiday is usually a day off?

"In the winter, in my country, we celebrate New Year.  1January is a public holiday and it is a day off."

Comment: I don't think you need the commas.  There is an issue, however, with your usage of *we celebrate New Year*.  In AmE we would either say "...we celebrate **the New Year**," or we would say, "...we celebrate **New Year's**," which is a shortened version of, "...we celebrate New Year's Day."  Additionally you would want to write, "January 1" or "January 1st" is a public holiday.

Comment: If I don't say that it's a public holiday, can I use "it's a day off"?

Comment: You can say "It's a day off" or "It's a public holiday" or "It's a public holiday and it's a day off".  All versions sound natural and they all convey the meaning.  Perhaps there is a bit of redundancy is saying it's a holiday and a day off but it sounds natural and no listener would ever give it a second thought.  Remember in the U.S. New Year's is often a two day affair with workers getting Dec 31st and Jan 1st as days off.  You may need to clarify that when you tell people what days are days off.

Comment: Isn't a public holiday always a day off? I am perhaps judging by my country because here each public holiday is a day off.

Comment: Take a look at:  https://www.quora.com/Are-they-both-right-take-a-day-off-work-take-a-day-off-from-work

Comment: In the U.S. a "public holiday" is not an official thing.  We would just call it a 'holiday' or maybe a 'national holiday'.  People now go shopping Thanksgiving day.  The people working at the stores that day do not have the day off.   (Even though they should.)